# How to print a String in a C++ Builder console application?

Tags: c++builder

I am trying to print the contents of a String in a console application. I am doing a test and would like to visualize the content for debugging purposes.

Here is my code:

```cpp
bool Tests::test001() {
    std::string temp;

    CDecoder decoder;  // Create an instance of the CDecoder class
    String input = "60000000190210703800000EC00000164593560001791662000000000000080000000002104302040235313531353135313531353153414C4535313030313233343536373831323334353637383930313233";
    String expected_output = "6000000019";
    String output = decoder.getTPDU(input);  // Call the getTPDU method
    std::cout << "Expected :" << expected_output.t_str() <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Obtained :" << output.t_str() <<std::endl;
    
    return output == expected_output;  // Return true if the output is as expected, false otherwise
}
```

This is what I get:

> Running test: 0
> Expected :024B8874
> Obtained :00527226
> Test Fail
> Press any key to continue...

This is what I want to get:

> Running test: 0
> Expected :6000000019
> Obtained :0000001902
> Test Fail
> Press any key to continue...

Here the Obtained value is a substring of the input I chose randomly (a shift to the left by two characters).

Whether I use t_str() or c_str() the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++Builder 2009 and later, `String` (aka [`System::String`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.String)) is an alias (ie, a `typedef`) for [`System::UnicodeString`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString), which is a UTF-16 string type based on `wchar_t` on Windows and `char16_t` on other platforms.

Also, the [`UnicodeString::t_str()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.t_str) method has been deprecated since around C++Builder 2010.  In modern versions, it just returns the same pointer as the [`UnicodeString::c_str()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.c_str) method.

You can't print a `UnicodeString`'s characters using `std::cout`.  You are getting *memory addresses* printed out instead of characters, because `std::cout` does not have an `operator<<` defined for `wchar_t*`/`char16_t*` pointers, but it does have one for `void*` pointers.

You need to use `std::wcout` instead, eg:

```
std::wcout << L"Expected :" << expected_output.c_str() << std::endl;
std::wcout << L"Obtained :" << output.c_str() << std::endl;
```

If you want to use `std::cout`, you will have to convert the `String` values to either [`System::UTF8String`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UTF8String) (and put the console into UTF-8 mode) or [`System::AnsiString`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiString) instead, eg:

```
std::cout << "Expected :" << AnsiString(expected_output).c_str() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Obtained :" << AnsiString(output).c_str() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the work:

> std::wcout

Here is the working code:

```cpp
// Member function to run test001
bool Tests::test001() {
    std::string temp;

    CDecoder decoder;  // Create an instance of the CDecoder class
    String input = "60000000190210703800000EC00000164593560001791662000000000000080000000002104302040235313531353135313531353153414C4535313030313233343536373831323334353637383930313233";
    String expected_output = "6000000019";
    String output = decoder.getTPDU(input);  // Call the getTPDU method
    std::wcout << "Expected: " << expected_output <<std::endl;
    std::wcout << "Obtained: " << output <<std::endl;

    return output == expected_output;  // Return true if the output is as expected, false otherwise
```